# How to handle urls in python urllib2 appengine with plus signs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2

Here's my problem. I'm trying to request a url from the rotten tomatoes API. Now the thing is that they require you to have your movie titles contain + signs where ever there should be spaces. However I'm not sure how to implement this on the app engine side, because whenever I try doing the same thing on app engine, I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/programming/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/programming/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/programming/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/programming/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/programming/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/programming/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/student/Desktop/Movie Rater/MovieRaterBackend/higgsmovies.py", line 12, in get
    page = urllib2.urlopen(site)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Here's my code:

```
    title = self.request.get("title")
    site = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=" + constants.ROTTEN_TOMATOES_KEY + "&q=" + title + "&page_limit=1"
    page = urllib2.urlopen(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    self.response.out.write(soup)
```

constants is just a python file containing all of my passwords and stuff, and I'm using beautiful soup to clean things up, but I'm sure that's not the problem. This code is just accessed by going to the url myapplication.com/about?title=your+title+goes+here, where myapplication will be the url of the website, probably some appspot.com url.

This works for URLs that don't contain + signs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you building the `title` string?  Are you simply replacing all spaces with plus signs?  Is it being URL encoded before you request it?

Comment: No, I'm not encoding it, but I tried replacing every plus sign with %2B if that's what you mean, that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: so how do I handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to handle the plus signs, because appengine seems to infer that these are new variables/values. However, using a regex other than '+' is a viable solution to the problem as a whole, as long as the application accessing the URL is able to replace [space]s with [regex] rather than the normal '+'. Seeing as the intended application of this service is to be a backend for an iPhone application, there should not be too much trouble with this method. I only have to make sure that my regex is not included in any movie names, and that it is not too long. For web applications using appengine to forward this kind of data to another online service, there is the possibility of writing a javascript script to handle this properly.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question, but have you tried using the [url fetch service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/), directly:

eg:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

title = self.request.get("title")
site = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=" + constants.ROTTEN_TOMATOES_KEY + "&q=" + title + "&page_limit=1"

result = urlfetch.fetch(site)
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either, I think it must be something with taking input from a url with + signs in it. I've put in a quick fix where I use a collection of random characters, something like 'ijaodfiadsf' so you'd get 'ManijaodfiadsfOfijaodfiadsfSteel' and then I change that into a string such as 'Man+Of+Steel', replacing all of the 'ijaodfiadsf's with '+'s, it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Plus signs ("+") are part of the standard for encoding form data: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)

Query strings, which are everything after the question mark ("?"), are form data -- or, in this case, REST query parameters.  So their API is behaving correctly here.

Comment: but that doesn't answer my question, or provide any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use `urllib.urlencode`.

Example:

```
params = { 'q' : 'value', 'apikey' : key_value }

request_url += urllib.urlencode(params)

urllib2.urlopen(request_url)
```